# markerclusterer check if marker is in cluster

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have a web based map that is using the [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) and [markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) plugin to make a google map.

I filter out which markers should be shown or not then update the map.

I need to create a list of unclustered markers and so to this end need a way to check clusters against markers and find out which are not clustered.

Is there any techniques to do this?

I have tried to cycle through clusters and manually check the markers against clusters but get an error telling me the clusters property `var_clusterer.clusters_` is not defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE**: This solution uses the [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/packages/markerclustererplus) library

You can use the getClusters() method to dish out an array of all the cluster objects currently being handled by MarkerClusterer.

```
var clusterManager = new MarkerClusterer( googleMap, markersArray, clusterOptions ); // setup a new MarkerClusterer

var clusters = clusterManager.getClusters(); // use the get clusters method which returns an array of objects

for( var i=0, l=clusters.length; i<l; i++ ){
    for( var j=0, le=clusters[i].markers_.length; j<le; j++ ){
        marker = clusters[i].markers_[j]; // <-- Here's your clustered marker
    }
}
```

After you get the array using getClusters() loop through the cluster objects. For each cluster you can pull the current `markers_` array and retrieve your clustered marker.

<strike>getClusters() is now in the docs: [MarkerClustererPlus docs](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)</strike>

Comment: Good news and bad news... Good news: I found the answer myself. It is exactly the same as you have described. Bad news: I spent over a week looking for the answer :-P . Anyone else with a similar issue should do the above. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Are you using MarkerClustererPlus, because in regular MarkerClusterer there is no method getClusters()?

Comment: @DejanStuparic If you have a look at the [docs](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.7/docs/reference.html#MarkerClusterer) they clearly show the `getClusters()` method..

Comment: for me it does not exist, i had to use
`var clusters = clusterManager.clusters_;`

Comment: For anyone using google.maps V3, it should be noted that `clusterer.getClusters()` returns all clusters including those with a marker count of 1 (ie. displayed as a marker not a cluster). If you are interested in knowing whether a particular marker is genuinely clustered, then (when looping through as above) you must test only those markers in clusters of length >1.

Comment: @hitautodestruct - the link you pointed out is indeed the  `MarkerClustererPlus` add-on that @DejanStuparic mentioned for the original `MarkerClusterer` library in order to get the `getClusters()` functionality.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:** using [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus) v2.1.10

```
isMarkerClustered(marker: Marker, clusterer: MarkerClusterer): boolean {
   const clusters = clusterer.getClusters();
   for (let i = 0, l = clusters.length; i < l; i++) {
      const markers = clusters[i].getMarkers();
      for (const m of markers) {
        if (m === marker && markers.length > 1) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly dump, but effective method....

You may insert markers individually to a Marker Clusterer Object, and immediately (1)before and (2)after, call its .getTotalCluster() method to see if the newly added marker will go into a cluster.

I use this method, after getClusters() didnt work for me, maybe Im not using it via jquery.

```
var old_cluster_val = markerCluster.getTotalClusters(); // <-----(1)
     markerCluster.addMarker( marker );
var new_cluster_val = markerCluster.getTotalClusters(); // <-----(2)

if (old_cluster_val == new_cluster_val) {
    in_a_cluster.push(marker);  
} else {
    not_in_cluster.push( marker );
}
```

Comment: it might be slightly dump but using markerCluster.getTotalClusters() for me always returns 0 even though there are obviously 11 markers in the array. what could be the problem?!